# How to keep track of powershell script invocation mode in PS background jobs and thread jobs?

Tags: multithreading, azure, powershell

I want to keep track of how a PowerShell script is getting invoked.
**Scenario:** I have a parent PowerShell script that logins to azure and install PowerShell modules. This script calls multiple PowerShell scripts in parallel using ThreadJob. In the child scripts, I am checking if the script is being called by another script or is running as the main script, and based on that choosing if login and installing modules needs to be done or not.

This is how I'm checking the condition

```
$scriptExecutionMode = "main"
if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty((Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope Local).Value.PSCommandPath)) {
    $scriptExecutionMode = "called"
}
```

The problem is that in thread jobs or background jobs, it is always taking the invocation mode as main causing to login and installing modules again. And there will be scenarios when I'll have to run these scripts as main scripts so cannot remove that part.

Comment: Why not just have a `-NoImport` parameter in the "child scripts" to indicate no module import is needed and then explicitly add that when calling from the main script?

Comment: Not a good approach for atomation. What about the login part?

Comment: Why is it not a good approach? What's wrong with being explicit? You can suppress the login behavior with the same (or a similar) parameter

Comment: Can you add a switch param (eg, `[switch]$RunAsThreadJob`) to your child scripts, then enable it when called by the parent, and check if it's present/$true in your child script?  This might prove useful in simulated unit test cases.